# Finding all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Find all of the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

I have a hint with the theorem of correspondence where the ideals in $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ are the ideals $r\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $r\mid n$.

I am not sure how to apply this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Clearly, you have to find all divisors of $n$.

Comment: @Bernard TeX SX??????????

Comment: It should say "where $ r\Bbb Z \supseteq n\Bbb Z$", which is equivalent to $\,r\mid n\,$ since contains = divides for principal ideals.

Comment: @Bernard Find all the divisors *while* not losing sight of the site for the questions!

Comment: For the quotient group(ring) $r\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z}$ to be defined, we need $n\Bbb{Z}$ to be a subgroup (subring) of $r\Bbb{Z}$. So at the very least $n\Bbb{Z} \subseteq r\Bbb{Z}$. Thus $n=ra$ for some $a \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Comment: @user10354138:  Sorry, I operate on both sites,and I had a hard day ;o)

Comment: The question is asking to find all of the ideals in the general format, that is what I am unsure of

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1657210/find-all-ideals-of-mathbbz-n?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The correspondance theorem yields that if $I$ is an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then there exists an unique $J$ ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ so that $n\mathbb{Z}\subset J$ and $I=J/n\mathbb{Z}$

Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an euclidean domain, $J=m\mathbb{Z}$ for some $m$ and $m\mid n$.

This basically gives away the answer, there are as many ideals of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as divisors of $n$. For example $\mathbb{Z}_6=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ has two ideals, for $6\mathbb{Z}\subset 2\mathbb{Z}$ and $6\mathbb{Z}\subset 3\mathbb{Z}$ and $6\mathbb{Z}$ has no other proper superideal (that is ideal containing it). So $\mathbb{Z}_6$ has two ideals (namely, $2\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $3\mathbb{Z}_6$)

PS: If you find this answer messy, please feel free to edit for clarification. Thank you very much

Comment: Shouldn't you have $I=J/n\mathbb Z$ instead?

Comment: Yeah, any mistakes you find feel free to edit it